# Finding birth certificate for Hungarian Grandmother Rozsa Czeiler born May 15, 1921, possibly Jewish turned Catholic

Tags: birth-records, records

My grandmother's son was Istvan Laszlo Mayer born 1941/11 /03 in Pecs Hungary.
Both my grandmother and grandfather I believe where separated during World War two.
My grandmother ended up in Dominican Republic with my dad when he was 8 and another guy Andreas Dittrich who gave them this new last name Once in Dominican Republic they showed as married the latin american style where the wife takes the husband's name with the adjective 'de'.
I have my dad's birth certificate with me and definitively he is the son of Istvan Mayer who I would also like to find. Some records show he could have been a prisoner in a concentration camp.

Comment: This is a little confusing. You say Istvan Mayer was your grandmother's son, which would be your father or your uncle, but then you say your father is the son of Istvan Mayer. Also, is Istvan Mayer still living?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any information on *where* Rózsa was born in 1921? There are some civil birth registrations available that late on FamilySearch, but very few of them are indexed. (I paged through Pécs [https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3Q9M-CSB5-VS1N?i=483&cat=690556] between mid-May and mid-August 1921, but did not turn her up. I checked that date range because there was a three-month deadline for reporting births and deaths.)

István László's birth in 1941 is of course much too recent to be online, but it sounds like you already have a register extract for it. (I presume that's what you mean by your "dad's birth certificate".) I'm guessing that his father -- i.e. Rózsa's husband -- was also István? Unfortunately, FamilySearch only has the civil registers for Pécs up to 1921 for all events, so if they got married in the same place as their child was born, then the record of it is not online.

Comment: Not directly relevant to your question, and you probably already have it, but there's a photograph included in her temporary residency application here: https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:33S7-9RL7-94FK?i=550